# Wordpress run function before plugin is updating

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to accomplish the following:

Whenever my plugin is updated via the wordpress plugin update function, I want it to execute a function which backs up certain plugin files first before the upgrade is running.

I was checking through available hooks on wordpress, however only found the upgrader_process_complete hook, which according to the wordpress codex website:

```
The upgrader_process_complete action hook is run when the download process for a plugin install or update finishes.
```

While "the download process" is a little bit unclear, I have checked in the source code and it appears that the hook is called AFTER the plugin has been installed, meaning the plugin files are already overwritten and cannot be backed up anymore.

Is there a way to accomplish this hook or is wordpress missing this functionality to call a function before the plugin update progress is initiated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `upgrade_pre_install` filter of WordPress which is executed before upgrade start to deactivate the plugins. check the snippet below, hope this will help to play around plugin backup before updates.

```
add_filter( 'upgrader_pre_install', 'deactivate_plugin_before_upgrade_callback', 10, 2 );
function deactivate_plugin_before_upgrade_callback( $return, $plugin ) {

if ( is_wp_error( $return ) ) { //Bypass.
    return $return;
}

// When in cron (background updates) don't deactivate the plugin, as we require a browser to reactivate it
if ( wp_doing_cron() ) {
    return $return;
}

$plugin = isset( $plugin['plugin'] ) ? $plugin['plugin'] : '';
if ( empty( $plugin ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'bad_request', $this->strings['bad_request'] );
}

if ( is_plugin_active( $plugin ) ) {
    //You can play with plugin zip download over here
    //Deactivate the plugin silently, Prevent deactivation hooks from running.
    deactivate_plugins( $plugin, true );
}

return $return;
```

}

Comment: thank you for your answer, let me try this real quick and I will let you know!

Comment: @Tom kindly accept the answer if it resolved your query which will help others too:)